# Can epoll identify the difference between "rising" and "falling" on an edge trigger?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gpio, epoll

I'm using epoll to identify button presses on GPIO pins (push button interface).

I've been using /sys/class/edge/gpio/gpioXXX/edge set to "rising" because I just want to identify button presses.

I want to allow the user to hold a button down to do something on a UI (think volume changing or something). To do this I need to identify which event is the "rising" event and the "falling" event. Now that /edge/ is set to both, I am indeed seeing two triggers on the epoll_wait loop. Problem is that there's no difference between the two.

I have a timer to ignore epoll events on a gap because my buttons have a bouncing effect, so I detect a rising edge and wait X milliseconds because the bounce would cause 1 press to trigger a couple times. This conveniently worked out such that quick presses don't register a press and release event, but a press and release event (longer than the gap in ms) registers two.

That long background is just to provide context for the issue. There is no difference in my epoll loop between 2 quick presses and a press and hold. Two quick presses would be two rising edge events. A long press and hold would be a rising and falling edge event. I cannot, in the code, tell the difference.

Some code included for context.

```
    u64 oldTime = getTime();
u64 newTime = getTime();
u64 gap = 0;
int n;
int epoll_fd = epoll_create(1);
if(epoll_fd == -1) {
    perror("Unable to create the epoll: ");
}
int gpio1_fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio1/value",O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
int gpio2_fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio2/value",O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
int gpio3_fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio3/value",O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);


char buf = 0;
struct epoll_event event;
struct epoll_event *events;
events = (struct epoll_event *) calloc(MAXEVENTS, sizeof(event));

/** DO THIS FOR ALL 3 **/
struct epoll_event event;
event.data.fd = fd;
event.events = EPOLLPRI;
int ret = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, gpio1_fd, &event);

while (1) {
    n = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, 10, 100);
    for (int fd_index = 0; fd_index < n; fd_index++) {
        int fd = events[fd_index].data.fd;
        if(fd == gpio1_fd || fd == gpio2_fd || fd == gpio3_fd){
            newTime = getMonotonicTime();
            gap = newTime - oldTime;

            if(gap <150){
                printf("SHORT GAP, SKIP %llu\n", gap);
                n = read(fd, &buf, 1);
                oldTime = getTime();
                continue;
            } else {
                printf("VALID GAP DETECTED:  %llu\n", gap);
                oldTime = getMonotonicTime();
                if (fd == gpio1_fd) {
                    seek = lseek(gpio1_fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    printf("1");
                    read_and_send_gpios(1);
                }
                if (fd == gpio2_fd) {
                    seek = lseek(gpio2_fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    printf("2");
                    read_and_send_gpios(2);
                }
                if (fd == gpio3_fd) {
                    seek = lseek(gpio3_fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    printf("3");
                    read_and_send_gpios(3);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `epoll` is only going to notify when a file (or file-like device, in this case) has some I/O event to react to. I'm not familiar with using `epoll` for GPIO, but are you not able to simply _read_ the value in the GPIO file device to determine whether the pin is set or not?

Comment: You'll have to read the file to get the state of the pin, I'm afraid. Fortunately `epoll` tells you when to look otherwise you can waste a lot of time checking.

Comment: You are using the old (deprecated) GPIO API. There's an example in tools/gpio (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/gpio/gpio-event-mon.c), which shows your use case with the new api (it does blocking reads, but extending it to epoll should be straightforward)